# Windows prompting to install .NET 3.5 when 4.x is installed

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-4.5, .net-4.6

I have a small command line application written in C#/.NET. I need it to run when .NET 3.5 or above is installed on the operating system.

To do so, I have the app.config contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

The project framework is setted to ".NET Framework 3.5".

From my understanding, these two settings should be backwards compatible so that when someone does not have 3.5 installed, but has 4.x installed, it will continue to work.

Is there something else I'm missing? From my research I thought that I had gotten all of the pieces together for this to work.

edit: Per the below question here are also the references and using statements. there are no third party components

the following are references in the project:

```
System.Core
System.Web.Extensions
System.Windows.Forms
```

and the following are my using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: Do you have third party components?

Comment: i do not, i will add references and using statements to the original question

Comment: Try to added `sku`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739412/require-the-net-4-0-full-profile-with-supportedruntime

Comment: @LexLi that appears to work for 4.0+, when using 4.0 as the target. when only 3.5 is installed on the system the application crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known restriction of .NET Framework - starting with 4, it does not allow an app to be executed within its own runtime if the previous (in your case, **target** version) is not installed.

3.5 is based on a different CLR (2.0), hence some compat issues. You'd need to re-target your project to 4.0 (or later) to avoid the issue of the framework install prompt.

Recommended reading:
[CLR Inside Out - In-Process Side-by-Side](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx)